# How to handle COM DLL call that can return object or error code in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, com

I am calling a COM dll from C#. I just added the DLL to my references and it seems to work fine as I can access its methods. In the documentation, this DLL has the following function that can return a specific object (void* This) or an error code (long) if the function can't open the file:

```
long APIENTRY OpenFile(void* This, LPSTR lpszFileName);
```

However, in C#, the method OpenFile is:

```
void OpenFile(string xyz);
```

I can therefore use it as follow:

```
public class MyClass {
  public COMdll.NewObject MyObject {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public COMdll.NewObject ReadObject(string filePath) {
    MyObject = new COMdll.NewObject();

    MyObject.OpenFile(filePath);

    return MyObject;
  }
}
```

But what happens if there is an error when opening the file and that error code (long) is returned?
How can I catch that in my C# code?